# MAUI App doesn't run: UINSWindowStateController error

Tags: c#, .net, rider

I try tu run my MAUI App in Rider (Mac) and when i click the .NET Icon to open the App,
the terminal shows me these erorrs:

`*** Assertion failure in -[UINSWindowStateController createAppropriateWindowForUserAppActivation], UINSWindowStateController.m:350`
and:
`[UINSWindowStateController createAppropriateWindowForUserAppActivation]: Trying to "relaunch" the app, and no scenes exist, but the app does not support multiwindow! We should always have a scene in this case.`

The solution worked until i create a repo and move the project in it.

I think that the problem may be in solution configuration
but i can't solve this problem.

Comment: have you builded app using pkgbuild or productbuild?

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Rider on a Mac and was able to fix this by running `Build > Rebuild Solution`